# First <div> automatically gets margin in HTML

Tags: html

Its one of those simple questions that bug the most. I have the following code:

```
<html><body>  
<style>  
div{background-color:######;}  
</style>  
<div>  
blah blah  
</div></body></html>
```

This in chrome and firefox displays a grey colored box with blah blah in it **but** with a small margin on the top,left and right. Ive tried explicitly putting the margin and padding as 0 but it still doesnt help...
any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set all margins and paddings to zero. HTML elements come with default formatting:

```
<html><body>
<style>
* {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
div{background-color:######;}
</style>
<div>
blah blah
</div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you heard about css reset?

http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/

Answer (score 1):

In my Firefox on Ubuntu, Firebug indicates that the margin you describe is an 8px margin that is applied to the body.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely it.

```
body{margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px}
```

So the final code is:

```
<html>
     <body>
<style>
div{background-color:######;} 
body{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px
    }
</style>
<div>
blah blah
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The page has a default margin. To remove it, you can use:

```
body { margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `<body>` Tag take margin so to remove it use this style in your css:

```
 body { margin: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `p { margin:0; padding:0; }` to `style` block.